# Explicit computation of a norm in context of operator-semigroups and differential equations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, linear-pde, semigroups-of-operators

I am interested in the explicit calculation of the following norm $\vert \cdot \vert$.
Let $X$ a Banach space with norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ and $(T(t))_{t \geq 0}$ a strongly continuous one-parameter semigroup on X (i.e.: $T(t): X \to X$ for all $t >0$), lets define $\vert \cdot \vert$
as $$ |x| = \sup_{t \geq 0} \Vert T(t)x \Vert $$ for all $x \in X.$ We assume that the semigroup is bounded so that the norm is well-defined. As we know the new norm $\vert \cdot \vert$ is equivalent to the original norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ on $X$. I am interested in that norm in context of ODEs/PDEs (especially non-symmetric evolution equations and long-time behaviour/asymptotics). Does this norm have a special name or does anyone know some helpful references for the calculation or useful properties of the norm? Would be very grateful for any references.

I tried to compute this norm for the matrix exponential of a (n by n)-matrix A with constant coefficients and A should be positive stable, where $T(t)x = \operatorname{e}^{-At}x$ can be seen as the solution of the following linear ODE with constant coefficients:

$x(t)=(x_1(t),\cdots,x_n(t))^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}^n:$
$$ \begin{cases}
    \frac{d}{dt}x=-Ax,t \geq 0.\\
    f(0)=x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n,
\end{cases} $$
with a real in general non-symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

So I would like to compute $$ |x| = \sup_{t \geq 0} \Vert \operatorname{e}^{-At}x \Vert $$ for  a given constant, positive stable (every Eigenvalue of A has positive real part) matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$
Is there an easy way to do this, or if not, are there references? Maybe with additional assumptions? Would be very grateful for any help!

Best regards

Comment: You probably want to assume your semigroup to be bounded in order for your new norm to be well-defined.

Comment: Yes, that is correct! Thanks for the hint, actually I am assuming a non-positive growth bound for the semigroup. (I edited that in the text.)

Comment: Maybe I should mention that this norm is amongst others used by A. Pazy in his textbook "Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations (1983)" in the proof of the Hille-Yosida Theorem in the non-contractive case to trace it back to the contractive case. Then if we endow $(T(t))_{t \geq 0}$ with the operator norm induced by the new norm $| \cdot |$ it yields a (quasi-)contractive semigroup.